# Forcing a delegated type in Rails `has_many`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have these models similar to the [DelegatedType](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) docs:

```
# Schema: entries[ id, title, created_at, updated_at, entryable_type, entryable_id ]
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  delegated_type :entryable, types: %w[ Message Comment ]
end

module Entryable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :entry, as: :entryable, touch: true
  end
end

# Schema: messages[ id, body ]
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  include Entryable
end

# Schema: comments[ id, content ]
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  include Entryable
end
```

And I'd like another model to **only** be related to a given type, say like so:

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end
```

If I then was to try and create it via say,

```
board.messages.create(title: 'foo', body: 'bar')
```

I'd get an error on `title` being an unknown attribute.

Though I can think of a way around this I was wondering if there is something I'm missing that makes it easy to have the delegated type of `Message` to be my association here?

Comment: why would you want to assign a value to a message's title when it doesn't have such a field?

Comment: From my understanding this would be better suited for a Polymorph than a Delegated Type. Delegated Types are not meant to stand alone, meaning you shouldn't use `Message.create(title: 'foo', body: 'bar')` (which is essentially what you are doing), instead this would be `Entry.create(entryable_type: 'Message', title: 'foo', entryable_attributes: { body: 'bar'})`. Additionally you have not provided any mechanism by which `Board` can "have many messages" because `Entry` does not belong to `Board`

Comment: My example probably wasn't as clear as it could have been. The equivalent of `Entry` will be more complex in my app and historically would've been an STI based set of models, but to remove the obsolete columns from individual types delegated types seemed a better fit. But in one relationship (the `Board` in my example above) it will only ever contain those with a `Message` as the `entryable`. Another benefit I get from delegated types is being able to surface multiple types in feed/searches easily.

Comment: No I think your example is fairly clear; however, as I mentioned delegated types are not intended to standalone. The control of what can and cannot be associated would need to be handled elsewhere. If want to ensure this you will need to add `board_id` to `Entry` and then validate that when `board_id` is present then `entryable_type` is `'Message'`. Otherwise you should be able to naturally control this be simply enforcing an interface that only allows `Message`s for `Board`s